Ubuntu login issue
I'm experiencing issues with my Ubuntu desktop. When I try to boot the system, I'm unable to access the desktop.
I've tried several troubleshooting steps to fix the issue, Booting from a live USB, Accessing recovery mode, Running fsck in terminal etc. Despite these efforts, the problem remains unresolved. I can see error messages during the boot process. I am looking for someone who can help me restore access to my Ubuntu desktop.

does it bonce you to the login after you type in your password?

It's stuck in the boot screen itself, wherein it says "started hold until boot process finishes up"
